# What is the difference between '割り引き' and '割引'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the difference between '割り引き' and '割引'?
Both pronounced as 'waribiki',meaning 'discount'.
Can somebody kindly advise, thanks.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42093/9831　・　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15822/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**割引** is the orthographically recommended form to represent the *noun* that means "discount".

**割り引き** is the recommended form to represent the 連用形 of the *verb* 割り引く "to discount". It's most likely to be used as a part of the polite form e.g. 割り引きます.

I wrote "recommended" because this part of Japanese orthography ([1](http://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kijun/naikaku/okurikana/honbun06.html), [2](http://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kijun/naikaku/okurikana/honbun07.html)) tolerates a certain degree of freedom (Japanese orthography isn't technically compulsory either, but it's another problem).

---

Below is the frequency data from [BCCWJ](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/) for your information:

- Noun

  - 割引: 1371
  - 割引き: 45
  - 割り引き: 38
- Verb (連用形-一般)

  - 割り引き: 5

Answer (score 1):

Difference is:

1. '割り引き' is full form of writing, the most correct one. It used when you have space and time :).
2. '割引' is shorter writing. It's acceptable when no time/space available to use form 1 above.
   They are the same, nobody will care which you use. Everyone will understand you, but in some places form 1 may be better (like Japanese lesson, when teacher wants to check you understand real reading on paper). In other places people may want to use shorter form 2. For example, in train, when they have no space on indicator, and 2 big letters will fit and can be readable easier, than smaller 4.

Comment: Since 割引 is significantly more common than 割り引き, I don't think it makes sense to say that 割り引き is more correct, especially since 割引 is listed in prescriptive language sources like the NHK漢字表記辞典.  See also http://www.mext.go.jp/b_menu/hakusho/nc/k19730618001/k19730618001.html

Comment: well OK, which is more correct "math" or "mathematics"? :) Same same they are. Same meaning, nobody cares which form who uses. In Your dictionary they used shorter one to fit more words into it. Shorter one is cool, easy usable, requires less time, space to write, but those り and き are always exist in speech, and very important. I'm not japanese specialist. It's just from my experience living in Japan for 10+ years.