# when should one use 支払い or 支払

Tags: orthography, kana-usage

In lots of contracts I see the word 支払. 
When should one use 支払 instead of 支払い?

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15821/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42093/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"支払" and "支払い" are almost same in the meaning and interchangeable with each other.
When to use them is also a very controversial issue even for Japanese and me.
From my understanding, "支払" is used mainly in official and commercial use including contracts and "支払い" is used in other cases.